# Batch Script - Displaying files and directory in sorted order

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

So I'm trying to make my own dir command for cmd. So far it is working great, except I want to output the directories and files sorted by file extension, in the way

```
dir /o:ge
```

would display (folders first, then files sorted by file extension).
So far, my code looks like this

```
@echo off

rem Title
echo.
echo CURRENT DIRECTORY [%cd%]
echo. 
rem Directories
for /d %%D in (*) do (
    echo [DIR] %%~nD
)

rem Files
for %%F in (*) do (
    echo %%~nxF
)
@echo on
```

This produces:

[image: Example]

I'm not sure how to approach outputting the files sorted by file extension. I have searched the web and can't find a solution to this problem. I  do realize batch script is very limited, but I still want to try and implement this. I have thought of using a for loop and storing all the file extensions into an "array" (if that exists in batch), and then outputting them by

```
*.fileExtension
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Derek

Comment: `Dir /B/A-D/OE` _…enter `Dir /?` at the command prompt for usage information._

Comment: The order you get with a for loop depends on the underlying file system. Only ntfs sorts with alpha sort by default. For also doesn't obey the environment var `Dircmd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment…

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo  CURRENT DIRECTORY [%__CD__:~,-1%]&Echo(
For /F "EOL= Tokens=* Delims= " %%A In ('Dir /B/AD/ON') Do Echo  [DIR] %%A
For /F "EOL= Tokens=* Delims= " %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D/OE') Do Echo  %%A
Echo(&Pause>Nul
```

Alternatively…

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo  CURRENT DIRECTORY [%__CD__:~,-1%]&Echo(
For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /OGE/-C'
) Do For /F "Tokens=3*" %%B In ("%%A"
) Do If "%%B"=="<DIR>" (If Not "%%C"=="." If Not "%%C"==".." Echo  [DIR] %%C
) Else Echo  %%C
Echo(&Pause>Nul
```

Comment: For the second method, it's supposed to output [DIR], not <DIR> right? I'm still getting <DIR> outputted.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the output from your `Dir` command contains an extra token. The method is not robust enough then due to locale settings differences. _To get the output though you'd probably need to use `Tokens=4*`_

Comment: That works great. Is there any way to order the directories in alphabetical order?

Comment: @DerekZhang `dir /OEGN` should group directories first, in alphapetical order, then files by extension.